# chrome back button not changing route to parent component in angular2

Tags: google-chrome, angular, router

am using

`route.navigate`

in Angular 2 to change the route from parent component to child  but when am clicking the chrome back its just stay in the same path after flix only, i test it in safari, it works .

the route am using

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserSitesComponent },
  { path: 'section-1/:sitename', component: HomeLayoutComponent },
  { path: 'section-2/:sitename/:sectionid', component: SectionEditComponent },
  { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent },
  // { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
];
```

when am navigating from

```
http://localhost:8888/section-1/mysite
```

to

```
http://localhost:8888/section-2/mysite/ab1234
```

using

```
this.route.navigate(['section-2/mysite/ab1234'])
```

it takes me to the required component, BUT !!?? when am clicking back button in chrome browser it did not send me back to

```
http://localhost:8888/section-1/mysite
```

the page just blinks and stay in same path, as if its try to change but faild, 
and am getting the following error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'loaded' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'loaded' of undefined
```

any idea ?

Comment: That's not enough information. This usually works. We would need a full example to be able to reproduce and debug.

Comment: Is `loaded` a name from your code?